# Identifying the method with higher Intraclass correlation coefficient on multiple dependent variables

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, manova, intraclass-correlation

I have a 24 subjects and for each subject 3 operators generate a 3D Mesh. I then have 4 methods to assign a coordinate system to those 24x3 3D meshes, the results are 3 orthogonal vectors, so 9 dependent variables, by 3D mesh. All dependent variable are inferior to 1. The operators are always the same.

The orientation for each subject is independent of the other.

I would like to see if one of the methods is more reliable than the other, meaning leading to lower within subject variation of the output variables ?